# How to prevent DIV from sliding after pressing TAB

Tags: html, css

I have a structure where there is a container and there are two slides in it. There is one text input field in each slide.

When input field on the first slide is focused, if user hits TAB key, automatically focus gets shifted on the input field of the second slide and second slide gets visible. (notice that `margin-left:0px !impotant` is still applied but still `DIV` is moved)

I don't want to disable TAB key which also means using `tabindex="-1"` is not a solution because it will isolate the text input from navigation .

I don't mind if focus is shifted to the second input field, but second slide should not move and get visible. I tried using `margin-left:0px !important` it didn't work.

How do I prevent this behavior using HTML and CSS?

[**Live Example is here**](http://cssdeck.com/labs/ooxikwec)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="inner">
        <input type="text" placeholder="please click me and hit tab">
    </div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:#797979">
       <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
  margin-top:200px;
  margin-left:300px;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  border:1px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.slider{
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-left:0px;
  height:100%;
  width:200%;
}
.inner{
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-left:0px;
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
  background:#cecece;
  float:left
}

input{
  width:200px;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-left:46px;
  height:40px;
  color:black;
  padding-left:2%
}
```

Comment: Actually when you press Tab the focus switches to the next input, this is why it "slides" as they are slightly offset.

Comment: but `margin-left` of its container is still `0px` how can it slide?

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this would be to add `tabindex="-1"` as a property to the second input field (or whichever ones are necessary, depending on your preference). It would look something like this:

```
...
  <input type="text" tabindex="-1">
...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That will isolate that particular text input from navigation, so it is as good as disabling TAB

Comment: Why would you ever want the user to tab to a second input field that is off screen? Kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: User might navigate to the second slide, where he might want to use tab to focus input field on the second slide.